# What is the probability for sequence of length $L$ in subset of $[n]$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I am trying to calculate the probability that I'll have a sequence of length $L$ in a random subset of $[n]$ when the subset size is $k$.

For example, if $n=5$, $k=4$ and $L=2$ I'll have the following subsets:

$$\{2,3,4,5\}, \{1,3,4,5\}, \{1,2,4,5\}, \{1,2,3,5\}, \{1,2,3,4\}$$

Thus the answer will be $1/5$ because there is only one subset that have $L=2$ sequence or for $L=3$ the answer will be $2/5$ etc.

Comment: So, when you write, "have a sequence of length $L$," you mean "the longest consecutive sequence should be of length $L$," is that right?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson No, that's mean that i'm defining the L, it shouldn't be the longest one.

Comment: FWIW, I understood the definition of L exactly as @GerryMyerson describes it in his comment and I fail to understand the answer in your comment.

Comment: Given $L$, what is the probability that a random $k$-subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ contains at least $L$ successive integers? (somewhere, maybe in several places). In Gerry's terms, the longest consecutive sequence should be of length $L$ or more. Of course, if you know one probability, you know the other, which makes me suspect that the exact answer is fairly ugly.

Comment: @Did i'm looking for the Pr(L=2|k=4) or Pr(L=3|k=4) or whatever..., i'm not looking for the longest L

Comment: Actually, your definition and your example contradict each other, hence the confusion. Nevertheless, as I said, it doesn't matter which way we understand the question :).

Comment: I never said you did, I said that at present nobody knows what it is you call L (that is, if L is not the quantity @GerryMyerson suggested).

Comment: @user61807 Maybe you can tell which $L$ value each of subsets you mentioned above corresponds to and why. It will help clarify the definition.

Comment: @polkjh The question is from all k-size subsets of [n], how many will have exactly L lenght sequence (if it has longest that L - it shouldn't be counted), or what is the probability that a choosen k-size subset have exactly L-size sequence

Comment: Ah, this is a third possible interpretation I overlooked. Now it is clear what is meant :).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection between binary numbers of length $n$ and [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of number $n+1$. And subsets of $[n]$ can be easily represented as binary numbers of length $n$. So we can represent subsets of $[n]$ by compositions of $n+1$.

Let $C(n,k,L)$ denote the number of subsets of $[n]$ in which the longest sequence of consecutive numbers is of length at most $L$. What we need is that sequence to have length exactly $L$, which is given by $C(n,k,L)-C(n,k,L-1)$.

Representing subsets as compositions, $C(n,k,L)$ corresponds to the number of compositions of $n+1$ into $n-k+1$ parts with each part at most $L+1$. This was answered in [Restricted Compositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/restricted-compositions).

Comment: I don't see where the L-size sequence is considered.

Comment: That is what $C(n,k,L)$ gives. It is the number of subsets with sequence size $L$ or less. So $C(n.k,L)-C(n,k,L-1)$ gives the number of subsets with exactly $L$-size sequences. And in compositions, this is forced by saying that each part is at most $L+1$. Is the mapping between compositions and subsets clear?

Comment: So I don't understand what does this C(n,k,l) means? c(n,k,l)=? (is there any equation?)

Comment: That is given in the link I gave above, to another question. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/restricted-compositions)