# Total number of solutions for a given equation with a minimum value $0$ and a maximum value of $m$

Tags: combinatorics

What is the total number of solutions for following equation

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+.....+x_k=n$$

with a maximum value of $m$, where $0\leq x \leq m$. No two variables should contain a maximum value $m$.

Example: $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$ with a maximum value $2$ ($n=3$, $m=2$, $k=3$)

Total possible ways is $7$:
$$\{1,1,1\}, \{0,1,2\}, \{0,2,1\}, \{1,0,2\}, \{1,2,0\}, \{2,0,1\}, \{2,1,0\}$$

I've done it manually but I don't how to come up with a formula. I've been struggling for last one week.
Is there any formula?

Comment: Do you know about generating functions?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about generating functions.Small correction is we can have x1+x2+...+xk variables not limited to m varables

Comment: @Malka: You can edit the question with the correction. I have done it for you.

Comment: Why is $\{0, 1, 2\}$ a valid solution, but $\{0, 1, 1, 1\}$ is not? I think your problem definition is missing something.

Comment: @JonathanRich:We have only 3 variables x1,x2 and x3 right and total sum we need is 3

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:Thank you,actually this is the first time I'm posting a question on any blog

Comment: So $k$ is also fixed (you have three parameters: $n$,$m$, $k$)?

Comment: What determines $k$?

Comment: @leonbloy:yes k is also fixed.I've n,m and k values and need total number of solutions

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can divide the solutions into two groups. One, those which attain the maximum value ($x_i = m$ for some  $i$, and $x_j < m$ for all $j\ne i$); the other, in which $x_i < m$ for all $i$.

Then you can count the cardinality of each set by looking into [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/restricted-compositions).

Specifically, adapting the linked [pdf](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf) (formula E, page 441), we get that the number of compositions of $k$ numbers $0\le x_i<m$ with $\sum x_i = n$ is given by

$$F(n,m,k)= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor} (-1)^j {k \choose j}{n+k - j \, m -1 \choose k-1}$$

Then we have

$$C(n,m,k) = k \, F(n-m,m,k-1) + F(n,m,k) $$

In your example:

$$C(3,2,3) = 3 \, F(1,2,2) + F(3,2,3) = 3 \times 2 + 1 = 7$$

Comment: :Will this formulat considers condition "Only one variable out of k variables contains maximum value m"?

Comment: Example:x1+x2+x3+x4=6 with max value 3.n=6,k=4,m=3.Solutions {3,3,0,0},{3,0,3,0},{0,3,3,0},{0,0,3,3} are invalid

Comment: Yes, that restriction is taken into account, see the hint, the two groups correspond (respectively) to the two terms in $C(n,m,k)$ formula

Comment: ... and, regarding your first comment, I gather that it actually should read "at most one variable" instead of "only one variable".

Comment: Is there any generic formula for given both minimum value and maximum values.

Comment: What about marking you past questions as answered before asking new questions?  http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask