# How many lists of 100 numbers (1 to 10 only) add to 700?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Each number is from one to ten inclusive only.  There are $100$ numbers in the ordered list. The total must be $700$.

How many such lists?

Note: if, as it happens, this is one of those math problems where only an approximation is known, that would be great.  (My guess is it's not "that" big, around $10^{20}$ maybe?)

Thank you!!

---

So, to be clear say you have a dice with sides labelled $1$-$10$. You roll it $100$ times, once every $10$ seconds in order. The result is, if you will, a specific array of $100$ numbers (each being $1$-$10$), each position labelled $1$ to $100$. The array must then add to $700$; how many such arrays??

---

Just to be absolutely clear, I believe the total of "all" such lists (so, there is no requirement to add to $700$; it can add to anything), is indeed, simply $1$ googol, ie, $10^{100}$.

Comment: Order doesnt matter does it?

Comment: You can derive a simple recurrence formula in the case without order, that if $f(r,s,n)$ is the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of $s$ integers between $1$ and $r$, then $f(r,s,n)=f(r-1,s,n)+f(r,s-1,n-r)$ - the first case being those sums which don't involve the number $r$, and the second being the case where there is at least one $r$.

Comment: Using the language of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), what you want is the number of $A$-restricted compositions of 700 into 100 parts with $A=\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$.

Comment: @semiclassical - magnificent!  Do you know, what is the count of the A-restricted compositions of 700 into 100 parts with A=1..10??  :)

Comment: I just noticed this [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/restricted-compositions) which is identical in scope if not in language to this one...

Comment: Simpler to state equivalent question: how many integers with at most $100$ digits have a sum of digits equal to $600$ (add $1$ to each digit to get the corresponding die roll, incleading any leading zeros to make exactly $100$ digits).

Comment: @JoeBlow: which answer helped *you* the most? It's not always the one that the most people liked best. Oh, I see... you've started a bounty. I thought you were asking about acceptance. Of course, if you accept an answer and don't award the bounty yourself, the bounty goes to the accepted answer when the grace period expires.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Generating Function Approach**

The coefficient of $x^{700}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{10})^{100}$ is the number you are looking for. This is because each choice of one of the summands in each term gives a unique choice for one of the $100$ numbers.

We can get an easier form by first noticing that the coefficient of $x^{700}$ above is the coefficient of $x^{600}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^9)^{100}$ and that 
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^9)^{100}
&=\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^{100}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{100}\binom{100}{j}\left(-x^{10}\right)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-100}{k}(-x)^k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{100}\binom{100}{j}\left(-x^{10}\right)^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+99}{k}x^k\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Now we just need to add up the contributions to $x^{600}$ in $(1)$ which comes from the terms where $k=600-10j$. Thus, the coefficient of $x^{600}$ in $(1)$ is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{60}(-1)^j\binom{100}{j}\binom{699-10j}{600-10j}\tag{2}
$$
which comes to
$$
12113063910758377468145174162592296408571398929\\1260198434849317132762403014516376282321342995
$$
or approximately $1.2113063910758377468\times10^{92}$

---

**Inclusion-Exclusion Approach**

To compute the number of ways for $100$ non-negative numbers to sum to $600$ we can use the usual [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach which gives
$$
\binom{699}{600}
$$
How many of these ways include a number $10$ or bigger? We can try to count this by sticking a chunk of $10$ stars into one of the $100$ places and counting how many ways to sum $100$ numbers to $600-10$. This gives
$$
\binom{100}{1}\binom{689}{590}
$$
but this counts twice the ways that include two numbers $10$ or bigger. To count these, we stick $2$ chunks of $10$ stars into two of the $100$ plaes and count how many ways to sum $100$ numbers to $600-20$. This gives
$$
\binom{100}{2}\binom{679}{580}
$$
We can apply [Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to get the number of ways for $100$ non-negative numbers less than $10$ to sum to $700$ to be
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{60}(-1)^j\binom{100}{j}\binom{699-10j}{600-10j}
$$
which is the same as gotten in $(2)$.

Comment: Great answer. Just two minor remarks: personally I would not omit parentheses in expressions of the form $\left(\sum_ja_jx^{cj}\right)\left(\sum_kb_kx^k\right)$ (or alternatively write them $\sum_j\sum_ka_jb_kx^{cj+k}$), and I would rewrite $\binom{k+99}k$ as $\binom{k+99}{99}$. But things are correct as written.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: the parentheses seems to be a stylistic preference since I don't think there is much confusion and I was thinking of combining the sums. As for $\binom{k+99}{k}$ vs $\binom{k+99}{99}$, it is true that for non-negative, integer $k$ they are the same (so who cares?), however, for integer $k\lt-99$, they are different: $\binom{k+99}{k}=0$ whereas $\binom{k+99}{99}=-\binom{-k-1}{99}$ which is not $0$. It is sometimes useful to use, $$\sum_{j=0}^{60}(-1)^j\binom{100}{j}\binom{699-10j}{600-10j}=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^j\binom{100}{j}\binom{699-10j}{600-10j}$$

Answer (score 23):

In the language of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), what you want are the number of $A$-restricted compositions of $n=700$ into $k=100$ parts where $A=\{1,2,\ldots,a\}$ with $a=10$. While I don't know a closed-form for this number, one can express such counting succinctly using formal power series. To represent our set $A$ of allowed terms, we use the formal polynomial $f_{a}(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{a} x^j = \dfrac{x-x^{a+1}}{1-x}$. If we square this, then the coefficient of a term $x^n$ will represent the number of ways in which two integers in $A$ can add to a total of $n$. This gives us the following result:

> The number of $A$-restricted compositions, with $A=\{1,2,\ldots a\}$, of $n$ into $k$ parts is the $n$th coefficient of $f_{10}(x)^k$, which we can express as $[x^n]\left(\dfrac{x-x^{a+1}}{1-x}\right)^k.$

Thus in the case at hand what we want to find (or at least estimate) is $\boxed{\displaystyle\left[x^{700}\right]\left(\dfrac{x-x^{11}}{1-x}\right)^{100}}$. Amazingly, this can be pulled off rather easily by [WolframAlpha](http://po.st/0Oejw1), yielding the rather impressive result of $$
\boxed{
\begin{align}
12113063910758377468145174162592296408571398929 &\\
1260198434849317132762403014516376282321342995 &\approx 1.2 \times 10^{92}
\end{align}
}
$$
For approximations, I suggest perusing Sedgwick and Flajolet's [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html) which is available for download on the book site. I may dig into there myself to see if anything is known or can be estimated about such numbers.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A037306 seems to have some pointers.

Comment: If someone can provide a better way to format that 92-digit number, please do!

Comment: What does the zero in $\{x,0,700\}$ (Wolfram Alpha notation) show?

Comment: @mathh: It means that we're expanding about $x=0$ (rather than, say, $x=1$).

Comment: @Semiclassical I have no knowledge about Taylor series (or anything similar) so far (I assume the zero is related to them). Is it true that when working with generating functions we can always simply write it as $\{x,0,k\}$ after the generating function, where $k$ is the coefficient we're searching for?

Comment: @mathh: If that's the form of your generating function, yes. Though, even if you don't know Taylor series, the notion of expanding about a different point is worth grasping: Suppose you start with a polynomial in $x$, and substitute $x=y-1$. Then your polynomial 'looks like' a series in powers of $y-1$, and since these terms vanish when $y=1$ we're 'expanding around $y=1$.' (This actually does matter in GFs, since expansions around $x=1$ give you cumulative totals of coefficients.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: There are $93$ digits in that number (and the reformatting clearly shows it is an odd number). Actually a rather easy counting problem...

Comment: token bounty for explaining what the hell Compositions are, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Note that the numbers being added together have mean $\mu_0=11/2$ and standard deviation $\sigma_0=\sqrt{33}/2$; by the central limit theorem, the distribution of the sum of $100$ such numbers is approximately a Gaussian with mean $\mu=100\mu_0 = 550$ and standard deviation $\sigma=10\sigma_0=5\sqrt{33}$.  The continuous Gaussian distribution is
$$
f(x,\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right);
$$
and to a first approximation you can ignore the correction from discreteness.  So the number you want is roughly
$$
N\approx 10^{100} \cdot f(700,550,5\sqrt{33})=\frac{10^{100}}{5\sqrt{33}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{150^2}{1650}\right)\\
= \frac{10^{100}}{5\sqrt{66\pi}}e^{-150/11}\approx 1.66\times 10^{92}.
$$
It is helpful to compare this to the computational result.  A simple Python implementation is the following:

```
def N(x, n, cache={(0,0):1}):
   if x<0 or (n==0 and x>0): return 0
   if not cache.has_key((x,n)):
      cache[(x,n)] = sum([N(x-i, n-1) for i in xrange(1,11)])
   return cache[(x,n)]
```

Then `N(700, 100) * 1.0` yields `1.2113063910758377e+92`.

Comment: Thanks for this cute alternative estimation.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Thanks, I was using the wrong standard deviation.  I think it's fixed now.

Comment: @mvw: By $\mu_0$ I'm referring to the mean of the candidate values, not the mean of the actually selected values.

Comment: That's nice insight.

Comment: Note: $\mu_0 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}i\right)/ 10$, $\sigma_0 =\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}(i-\mu_0)^2\right)/10}$.

Comment: This answer would appear to be an incredibly clever alternate approach to an approximaation, am I right?!  Amazing...

Comment: I find it impressive how much the CLT estimation is off the mark, a full 37%!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: well, note that we're looking at a point way in the low-probability tail.  The probability that the numbers sum to $550$ (the exact mean) is $0.013868$, and the CLT estimate there is $0.013889$, or only $0.15$% off.

Comment: Ahh!  I suspected e92 seemed ridiculously small right?

Answer (score 7):

For a calculation answer, I get about $1.21131 \cdot 10^{92}$  I just made an Excel sheet with rows labeled -9 through 100 and columns 1 through 100.  The rows represent the number of ways to make that sum with the number of numbers $1$ through $10$ in the column heading.  Under column 1,put $1$ in each row $1$ through $10$.  Then in subsequent columns each cell is the sum of ten entries in the column to the left, from one above to ten above.  The rows with negative numbers in them are there so I didn't have to cut off the early sums, like for a sum of $3$ from two numbers.

Here is the top corner of the sheet:
$$
\begin {array}  {l l l l l }
tot&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
1&1&&&\\2&1&1&0&0\\3&1&2&1&0\\4&1&3&3&1\\5&1&4&6&4\\6&1&5&10&10\\7&1&6&15&20\\8&1&7&21&35\\9&1&8&28&56\\10&1&9&36&84\\11&&10&45&120\\12&&9&55&165\\13&&8&63&220\\14&&7&69&282\\15&&6&73&348\\16&&5&75&415\\17&&4&75&480\\18&&3&73&540\\19&&2&69&592\\20&&1&63&633\\21&&0&55&660\\22&&0&45&670\\23&&0&36&660\\24&&0&28&633\\25&&0&21&592\\26&&0&15&540\\27&&0&10&480\\28&&0&6&415\\29&&0&3&348\\30&&0&1&282\\31&&0&0&220\\32&&0&0&165\\33&&0&0&120\\34&&0&0&84\\35&&0&0&56\\36&&0&0&35\\37&&0&0&20\\38&&0&0&10\\39&&0&0&4\\40&&0&0&1\\ \end {array}
$$

Comment: hell - I'd have to really think about that!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://po.st/0Oejw1) gives a result of roughly $1.2\times 10^{92}$. Not sure whether that's a matter of Excel/WA breaking down or a typo in one of our implementations.

Comment: @Semiclassical:  I would guess it is Excel numerics, but am surprised the discrepancy is that large.

Comment: Aye. A 20% discrepancy would make sense for an approximation, but not for a direct count.

Comment: @Semiclassical  Yes, but we are adding terms here that vary much in magnitude.  Excel does things to about 15 decimal digits, so it seems a large error.  I checked that the sums of the columns are correct, so I believe the one expression I wrote is correct.

Comment: Are 15 significant figures per number enough, though? For any single quantity that might be very good precision, but when adding up so many terms all of that round-off error accumulates. (Though that column sum check is a good thought.) Probably the only way to be sure is to compare WA/Excel at smaller numbers where there shouldn't be any problems, and confirm that they agree up to that point.

Comment: I think you may just be looking in the wrong place… your result is the correct number of ways to make $701$ from a list of one hundred numbers in $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx:  Bingo.  Thanks.  I'll fix

Comment: @Semiclassical:  mystery solved thanks to mjqxxxx

Comment: Hell -- I'm struggling to understand this method!  Damn...

Comment: @JoeBlow:  It is the same idea as finding the number of ways to make sums from 2,3,4 dice.  There is exactly one way to make all sums from 1 to 6 with one die.  To make a sum of 8 with two dice, you need to start with 2 through 7 on the first die.  There is one way to do each of 2 through 6 and no ways t make 7, so there are five ways to make eight with two dice.  Then to make 14 with three dice, you add the number of ways to make 8 through 13 with two dice.

Comment: Hell - I have to think on that.  THANKS

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{0 < a < 1}$:

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k_{1}=1}^{10}\ldots\sum_{k_{100}=1}^{10}
> \delta_{k_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ x_{100},700}}
> =\sum_{k_{1}=1}^{10}\ldots\sum_{k_{100}=1}^{10}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
> {1 \over z^{-k_{1}\ -\ \cdots\ -\ k_{100}\ +\ 701}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}
> {1 \over z^{701}}\,\pars{\sum_{k =1}^{10}z^{k}}^{100}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{701}}\,\pars{z\,{z^{10} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{100}
> \,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{601}}\,
> {\pars{1 - z^{10}}^{100} \over \pars{1 - z}^{100}}\,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{100}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + k}{100 \choose n}
> {-100 \choose k}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{1 \over z^{601 - 10n - k}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{100}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + k}{100 \choose n}
> \pars{-1}^{k}{k + 99 \choose 99}\delta_{10n + k,600}
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{100}\pars{-1}^{n}{100 \choose n}{699 - 10n \choose 99}
> \end{align}

Contributions to the sum are limited by $\quad\ds{0 \leq n \leq 100}\quad$
and $\quad\ds{99 \leq 699 - 10n}\quad$ which yield $\quad\ds{0 \leq n \leq 60}$:

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k_{1}=1}^{10}\ldots\sum_{k_{100}=1}^{10}
\delta_{k_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ x_{100},700}
=\sum_{n = 0}^{60}\pars{-1}^{n}{100 \choose n}{699 - 10n \choose 99}}
$$
which is $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \pars{1}~}}$ equal to $\ds{\bracks{z^{600}}\pars{1 - z^{10} \over 1 - z}^{100}}$.

> It leads to the value
>   \begin{align}&
> {\tt 1.211306391075837746814517416259229640857139892912601984348493171327624}
> \\
> &{\tt 03014516376282321342995 \times 10^{92}}
> \end{align}

[It is found with W & A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5En+Binomial%5B100%2C+n%5D+Binomial%5B699+-+10+n%2C+99%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C++++++60%7D%5D).

Comment: Wow.  I bet, this would help generalise the problem, too.

Comment: Compared to the approach by robjohn, I'm don't see any insight that is gained by the use of contour integrals (rather the contrary).

Comment: Marc ... uh, obviously!  :-)  Thanks for that; I'm trying to make sense of what is different, natty, solid, etc!

Comment: @JoeBlow It's true. It lets you to set a general formula if you want. It avoids  'intermediate steps' that involve "counting" which is the most difficult situation. It's straightforward. Maybe, it takes a little bit to realize that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[A066099](https://oeis.org/A066099) features a nice visual generation pattern for compositions of $n$ (listing them in reverse lexical order):

```
From Omar E. Pol, Sep 03 2013:       

-----------------------------------  ----------
n  j       Diagram   Composition j   Row length
-----------------------------------  ----------
.               _
1  1           |_|   1;              1
.             _ _
2  1         |  _|   2,              1
2  2         |_|_|   1, 1;           2
.           _ _ _
3  1       |    _|   3,              1
3  2       |  _|_|   2, 1,           2
3  3       | |  _|   1, 2,           2 
3  4       |_|_|_|   1, 1, 1;        3
.         _ _ _ _
4  1     |      _|   4,              1
4  2     |    _|_|   3, 1,           2
4  3     |   |  _|   2, 2,           2
4  4     |  _|_|_|   2, 1, 1,        3
4  5     | |    _|   1, 3,           2
4  6     | |  _|_|   1, 2, 1,        3
4  7     | | |  _|   1, 1, 2,        3
4  8     |_|_|_|_|   1, 1, 1, 1;     4
.
```

So we would need that diagramm for $n = 700$ and only those
rows with $100$ summands and all summands from $\{1, \ldots, 10 \}$.

Pragmatic problem: There are $N = 2.63 \times 10^{210}$ compositions of $700$, according to WolframAlpha [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+compositions+of+700).

Looking at the diagram one notices that $N(n)$ is resulting from the doubling (see step 3 of the algorithm below) and is thus simply 
$N(n) = 2^{N-1}$ ([A000225](https://oeis.org/A000225)) and in this case: $N(700) = 2^{699}$.

About the recursion involved:

1. The list of compositions for $n+1$ can be obtained, by using a copy of the list for $n$ first.
2. Then we put a column of $1$ elements to the left of that list.
3. Finally we put another copy of the list for $n$ on top, shifted one position left, aligning with the column of $1$ elements, and adding $1$ to each entry in the first column of the copy.

Side note: It is already interesting to see how the row lengths develop:

> 1
>     1 2
>     1 2 2 3
>     1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4
>     1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5

If we have $2^n$ terms, we find the next $2^n$ terms by copying the first $2^n$ terms plus $1$ each.

This leads to [A063787](https://oeis.org/A063787) and is related to 
[A000120 (binary weight of $n$)](https://oeis.org/A000120).
They are described as *fractal sequences* - deleting every other term gives the original series.

Answer (score 1):

As this seems to be a programmer's problem, I will give you a sketch of the solution. For sake of completeness, I should advise you that this kind of problems should be posted in the correct stack exchange forum.

You certainly have been familiar with DP. So this problem should be solved in that manner.
You should look to a certain function, namely $f(n, m)$ that gives you the number of ordered sequences of $n$ integers in $A = \{1, \cdots, 10\} $ that sum $m$. You want $f(100, 700)$.

You should know a recursive way of computing this, as any sequence $a_1, \cdots , a_n$ that sums $m$ leads bijectively to a smaller sequence $a_1, \cdots , a_{n-1}$ that sum $m-a_n$
So $$f(n, m) = \sum_{k \in A}^{ m - k \geq 0} f(n-1, m-k)$$

You should initialize your function in $f(n, n) = 1$ and $f(1, m) = 1$ for $m\in A$, $f(1, m)=0 $ for $ m> 10 $. And now is just a question of programming.

Comment: It is a valid combinatorics problem.

Comment: I wont deny it. I just though that the OP wouldn't be interested in the generating function solution. My bad if it is not the case.

Comment: +1 Have you tried just entering the recurrence and conditions into Mathematica. That probably gives the answer and the programming is minimal. Too pressed for time right now to try it!

Comment: I can absolutely assure you that very few top software engineers, can do, the math on this page  :-)